# Strategies for making platform level decisions within a bundle

Tags: osgi

I have a requirement where, if one bundle fails to start because of some internal state issue, the entire application should not be running and thus the platform should be shutdown (`bundleCtx.getBundle(0).stop()`).

Because of OSGi's nice modularity and so on, other bundles might've started up just fine.

It feels kinda wrong for bundles to be calling `bundleCtx.getBundle(0).stop()` (or `System.exit(nn)` if a `BundleException` occurs) in different places.

Is there a common way to implement this? One way may be Declarative Services, but those are only notified when a given component starts, right? It cannot tell if something has failed (AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, here is one possibility I just stumbled upon.

I have a bootstrap bundle which is responsible for starting all of the other bundles in my app. It does this with `START_TRANSIENT`.

I could put logic into this bundle to do certain things depending on which bundle failed.

Answer (score 0):

So one idea would be to have one bundle that checks if all needed services and bundles come up. It can then stop the framework if one or more services are missing or if a bundle does not start. This would allow to centralize the checking logic at one place.

Comment: But when would that bundle perform the check? There are no guarantees around when a bundle or service will start and no synchronicity. I know I want them "kind of" at application start time, but the exact timings are out of my control.

Comment: You need to wait for the services and react when a timeout happens.

Comment: I suppose at the time resolution we are talking about (seconds), that would work.